# How to call @extends in a multiple file?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I am refactoring my laravel project into more isolated and as i read that it is always good to use `@extends/@yield` rather than `@includes` and besides as i continuing develop my projects it becomes more difficult and that layout is getting mess up. Considering this structure folder:

```
views
    categories
        index.blade.php
        show.blade.php
        ...
    layouts
        sidenav
            homesidenav.blade.php
            contentsidenav.blade.php
        header.blade.php
        footer.blade.php
        master.blade.php
```

Now i am having problem in yielding header and footer from my `master.blade.php`. I did this, though i am not sure if this is the right way:

```
<body>
    @yield('header')
    @yield('content')
    @yield('footer')
</body>
```

and on my `header.blade.php`, i have this:

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('header')
    //All header content here
@endsection
```

and on my model pages(index.blade.php), i have this:

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('title', 'Category List')

@section('content')
    //All main content here
@endsection
```

When i access my category index page, my header and footer are not included on my result. What mistake i have made?

Comment: header and footer should be includes

Comment: If i use @include i don't know why some of my layout is getting change, for example my header is getting displaying after my content.

Comment: sounds like a structural issue with the html

Comment: Perhaps? but if i put them in one file everything is good. For example header, content, footer in my ```index.blade.php```.

Answer (score 0):

The header and footer should be includes as they need to be 'included' in the main layout and aren't sections that you will be defining in extended templates and yielding.

```
<body>
    @include('layouts.header')

    @yield('content')

    @include('layouts.footer')
</body>
```